# Python numpy.matrix auxiliary matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am new to python and I could not find the answer to the following problem:

Let

```
import numpy as np
graph = np.matrix('1 1 1 0 0; 1 1 0 1 1; 1 0 1 0 0; 0 1 0 1 0; 0 1 0 0 1')
G = graph
G[1,:] *=2
print(graph)
print(G)
```

I would expect:

```
print(graph)

[[1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1]]

>>> print(G)

[[1 1 1 0 0]
 [2 2 0 2 2]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1]]
```

The result is

```
print(graph)

[[1 1 1 0 0]
 [2 2 0 2 2]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1]]

>>> print(G)

[[1 1 1 0 0]
 [2 2 0 2 2]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1]]
```

So my original graph was changed, although I did not perform any operation on it. As I see it python uses references\pointers not the acctual values. My question is how do I introduce the auxiliary matrix - so that I can work on it without changing my original matrix

Comment: `G = graph` doesn't make a new graph.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that, the problem is I do not know what does make a new one

Comment: ```G = graph.copy()```.

Comment: Thank You that was exactly what I needed